# After using optimization with root the results aren't what they should be

Tags: optimization, python-2.7, scipy

I've been using the root function  that comes from  "from scipy.optimize import root" in the solution of other problems that requires two equations, f(x,y) and g(x,y), so far I haven't found any hindrance until now,
the whole topic is of potential flow, and this particular problem is about a vortex + an steady velocity over a surface,
the next code is about finding the coordinates of a point P, (Xp, YP) in with the velocity is zero , with a vortex (intensity of the vortex = -550) over a surface, and this vortex is at the left of a wall.
U : steady velocity
cv : vortex intensity
h : the distance between the vortex  and the surface

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root
from math import pi

cv = -550.0
U = 10.0
h = 18.0

'''
denom1 = (X + h) ** 2 + Y ** 2
denom2 = (X - h) ** 2 + Y ** 2

###########################################
# f(x,y)
###########################################

f_1_a1 = - cv * Y / denom1
f_1_a2 =   cv * Y / denom2

# f(x, y)
f_1 = f_1_a1 + f_1_a2

dfx_1 = (- cv * Y) * ((-1) * (2) * (X + h)) / (denom1 ** 2)
dfx_2 = (cv * Y) * ((-1) * (2) * (X - h)) / (denom2 ** 2)

# df_x
d_f_1_x = dfx_1 + dfx_2


dfy_1 = (- cv) / denom1
dfy_2 = (- cv * Y) * (- 1) * (2) * (Y) /(denom1 ** 2)
dfy_3 = (cv) / denom2
dfy_4 = (cv * Y) * (-1) * (2 * Y) /(denom2 ** 2)

# df_y
d_f_1_y = dfy_1 + dfy_2 + dfy_3 + dfy_4


###########################################
# g(x,y)
###########################################

g_a1 = - U
g_a2 =   cv * (X + h) / denom1
g_a3 = - cv * (X - h) / denom2

# g(x, y)
f_2 = g_a1 + g_a2 + g_a3

dgx_1 = cv / denom1
dgx_2 = cv * (X + h) * (-1) * (2) * (X + h) / (denom1 ** 2)
dgx_3 = (- cv) / denom2
dgx_4 = (- cv) * (X - h) * (-1) * (2) * (X - h) / denom2
dgx = dgx_1 + dgx_2 + dgx_3 + dgx_3 + dgx_4
# dg_x
d_f_2_x = dgx

dgy_1 = cv * (X + h) * (-1) * (2) * (Y) / (denom1 ** 2)
dgy_2 = (- cv) * (X - h) * (-1) * (2 * Y) / (denom2 ** 2)
dgy = dgy_1 + dgy_2
# dg_y
d_f_2_y = dgy
'''

def Proof(X, Y):

    denom1 = (X + h) ** 2 + Y ** 2
    denom2 = (X - h) ** 2 + Y ** 2

    ###########################################
    # f(x,y)
    ###########################################

    f_1_a1 = - cv * Y / denom1
    f_1_a2 =   cv * Y / denom2

    # f(x, y)
    f_1 = f_1_a1 + f_1_a2

    dfx_1 = (- cv * Y) * ((-1) * (2) * (X + h)) / (denom1 ** 2)
    dfx_2 = (cv * Y) * ((-1) * (2) * (X - h)) / (denom2 ** 2)

    # df_x
    d_f_1_x = dfx_1 + dfx_2


    dfy_1 = (- cv) / denom1
    dfy_2 = (- cv * Y) * (- 1) * (2) * (Y) /(denom1 ** 2)
    dfy_3 = (cv) / denom2
    dfy_4 = (cv * Y) * (-1) * (2 * Y) /(denom2 ** 2)

    # df_y
    d_f_1_y = dfy_1 + dfy_2 + dfy_3 + dfy_4


    ###########################################
    # g(x,y)
    ###########################################

    g_a1 = - U
    g_a2 =   cv * (X + h) / denom1
    g_a3 = - cv * (X - h) / denom2

    # g(x, y)
    f_2 = g_a1 + g_a2 + g_a3

    dgx_1 = cv / denom1
    dgx_2 = cv * (X + h) * (-1) * (2) * (X + h) / (denom1 ** 2)
    dgx_3 = (- cv) / denom2
    dgx_4 = (- cv) * (X - h) * (-1) * (2) * (X - h) / denom2
    dgx = dgx_1 + dgx_2 + dgx_3 + dgx_3 + dgx_4
    # dg_x
    d_f_2_x = dgx

    dgy_1 = cv * (X + h) * (-1) * (2) * (Y) / (denom1 ** 2)
    dgy_2 = (- cv) * (X - h) * (-1) * (2 * Y) / (denom2 ** 2)
    dgy = dgy_1 + dgy_2
    # dg_y
    d_f_2_y = dgy

    print "The values of u and v are:"
    print f_1
    print f_2
    print "The derivates are:"
    print dgx, dgy
    print d_f_1_x, d_f_1_y

def fun_imp1(x):
    X = x[0]
    Y = x[1]

    denom1 = (X + h) ** 2 + Y ** 2
    denom2 = (X - h) ** 2 + Y ** 2

    ###########################################
    # f(x,y)
    ###########################################

    f_1_a1 = - cv * Y / denom1
    f_1_a2 =   cv * Y / denom2

    # f(x, y)
    f_1 = f_1_a1 + f_1_a2

    dfx_1 = (- cv * Y) * ((-1) * (2) * (X + h)) / (denom1 ** 2)
    dfx_2 = (cv * Y) * ((-1) * (2) * (X - h)) / (denom2 ** 2)

    # df_x
    d_f_1_x = dfx_1 + dfx_2


    dfy_1 = (- cv) / denom1
    dfy_2 = (- cv * Y) * (- 1) * (2) * (Y) /(denom1 ** 2)
    dfy_3 = (cv) / denom2
    dfy_4 = (cv * Y) * (-1) * (2 * Y) /(denom2 ** 2)

    # df_y
    d_f_1_y = dfy_1 + dfy_2 + dfy_3 + dfy_4


    ###########################################
    # g(x,y)
    ###########################################

    g_a1 = - U
    g_a2 =   cv * (X + h) / denom1
    g_a3 = - cv * (X - h) / denom2

    # g(x, y)
    f_2 = g_a1 + g_a2 + g_a3

    dgx_1 = cv / denom1
    dgx_2 = cv * (X + h) * (-1) * (2) * (X + h) / (denom1 ** 2)
    dgx_3 = (- cv) / denom2
    dgx_4 = (- cv) * (X - h) * (-1) * (2) * (X - h) / denom2
    dgx = dgx_1 + dgx_2 + dgx_3 + dgx_3 + dgx_4
    # dg_x
    d_f_2_x = dgx

    dgy_1 = cv * (X + h) * (-1) * (2) * (Y) / (denom1 ** 2)
    dgy_2 = (- cv) * (X - h) * (-1) * (2 * Y) / (denom2 ** 2)
    dgy = dgy_1 + dgy_2
    # dg_y
    d_f_2_y = dgy

    a_1 = f_1
    a_2 = f_2
    b_1 = d_f_1_x
    b_2 = d_f_1_y
    c_1 = d_f_2_x
    c_2 = d_f_2_y
    f = [ a_1,
         a_2]
    df = np.array([[b_1, b_2],
                   [c_1, c_2]])
    return f, df

sol = root(fun_imp1, [ 1, 1], jac = True, method = 'lm')
print "x = ", sol.x
print "x0 =", sol.x[1]
print "y0 =", sol.x[0]
x_1 = sol.x[0]
x_2 = sol.x[1]
Proof(x_1, x_2)
```

And just one of the components of the velocity is zero with the result that the program finds.
At first I thought that it was a problem with the derivatives but I haven't found any problem there. A friend of mine  once said that sometimes the intensity of the vortex could behave of different ways when it's too high (like over 150).

---

Added information:

this is the plot of the streamlines:

[image: plot of the streamlines]

after using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vortex_height = 18.0
h = vortex_height
vortex_intensity = -550.0
cv = vortex_intensity
permanent_speed = 10
U1 = permanent_speed

Y, X = np.mgrid[-21:21:100j, -21:21:100j]
U = (- cv * Y) / ((X + h)**2 + (Y ** 2)) + (cv * Y) / ((X - h)**2 + (Y ** 2))
V = - U1 + (cv * (X + h)) / ((X + h)**2 + (Y ** 2)) - (cv * (X - h)) / ((X - h)**2 + (Y ** 2))
speed = np.sqrt(U*U + V*V)

plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=U, linewidth=2, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)
plt.colorbar()

plt.savefig("stream_plot.png")
plt.show()
```

And the results that I got with the program are:

```
>>>
x =  [  1.32580109e-01   3.98170636e+02]
x0 = 398.170635755
y0 = 0.132580109151
The values of u and v are:
-8.2830922107e-05
-10.1246349802
The derivates are:
-2.20709329055 0.000624761030349
-0.000624761030349 6.22388943399e-07
>>>
```

where u and v should be :

u = 0.0
v = 0.0

instead of :

u = -8.2830922107e-05 (this one is acceptable)
v = -10.1246349802  (this is absolutely wrong)

And when I change it to 'hybr' in

```
sol = root(fun_imp1, [ 1, 1], jac = True, method = 'hybr')
```

I get this:

```
>>>
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py:221: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the
  improvement from the last ten iterations.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
x =  [ -4.81817071e+02   1.96057929e+06]
x0 = 1960579.2949
y0 = -481.817070593
The values of u and v are:
2.53176901102e-12
-10.0000000052
The derivates are:
-7.14899730857e-05 5.25462578799e-15
-5.25462578799e-15 -3.87401132188e-18
>>>
```

I got something similar once but I don't remember very well, I think  that in that other case was because of a bad derivation of the functions by hand, and in this present problem I haven't tracked any error on that aspect.

Comment: what is the value of `sol.success`? do you get the same solution without passing the Jacobian? What do you mean with what is the result not what it should be? Have you plotted the flow field to see if the result makes sense? please edit the question with this information

Comment: The `hybr` solver should have `sol.success == False`; you should check the result. The `lm` solver is different, since it solves it in least-squares sense and returns with success even if it isn't a real root.

Answer (score 3):

You use `method='lm'`, which according to the documentation solves the equation in the least-squares sense only. Using `method="hybr"`, you get `sol.success == False`.

Quite possibly, your jacobian is incorrect, as a root is found with `jac=False`.

**EDIT**: your Jacobian seems to be wrong, at the least:

```
x = np.array([3, 3.])
dx = np.array([1.3, 0.3])
eps = 1e-5
dx = 1e-5 * dx / np.linalg.norm(dx)

df_num = (np.array(fun_imp1(x + dx/2)[0]) - np.array(fun_imp1(x - dx/2)[0])) / eps
df_cmp = fun_imp1(x)[1].dot(dx)/eps

print df_num
print df_cmp
```

prints

```
[-1.43834392 -0.69055079]
[   -1.43834392 -1024.60208799]
```

It's very useful to *always* check Jacobians against numerical differentiation.

Comment: I was thinking that, due to the high intensity of the vortex, there are two coordinates that give a velocity (almost) equal to zero so I did it , using the change of U = 10.0 to  U = -10.0  (maybe I was wrong at the begining), and there are better results without using the root because the I just have to deal with 'y' and not with 'x'.